# mongoose / mongodb - reference value from another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Learning in progress - Stuck working out how have to have 2 separate documents in different collections: **events** & **event reviews**

I'm able to reference objectId's between the two but what's the best way to reference data from within those documents if I wanted to populate information from the **event** into the **event review** as it's created? I've been trying to trying to google the answer for a few hours now but have so far been unsuccessful with each method I've found. Not looking for a specific answer just somebody with a bit more knowledge to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do beyond Mongoose's support for [population](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)?

Comment: Are You Trying to store the object id from event into event review ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly state that a field in your event reviews schema references the ObjectID of a document in your event collection. Like so...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'), Schema = mongoose.Schema
var EventReviewSchema = new Schema({
   someField:{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: 'Event'   // Note this is the name of the event model, not schema
     }
})
```

You mentioned that you want to do this "as it's created."

Remember that in MongoDB, *write operations are only atomic at the single document level*. So there is no "built in" way to guarantee that every event document you create will have a corresponding event review document (I assume that this is what you're trying to do.)

You will need to save an event document, grab that document's ObjectId and use it to populate the appropriate field in your event review document. But remember, there is chance that the second write operation will fail if some error occurs between the time of the first and second write operation.

My advice is to try to write your application in a way that can use a mongoose FindOrCreate method (with a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-findorcreate)) when querying for event review documents. It's a quick and dirty way to solve this problem.

EDIT:

```
var Review = mongoose.model('Review', EventReviewSchema)

module.exports.reviewCreate = function(req, res, next) { 
    var eventid = req.params.eventid
    if (eventid) { 
        var review = new Review() // Review model
        review.someField = eventId
        review.save(function(err){
            if(err) return next(err)
            // save successful
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is one of the methods I had attempted and is similar to how I reference the objectId. The part I'm not understanding, is based on the information above, what is required on the module side to specifically reference the required data. Here's what I thought would work (but does not). Am I missing a step?    
`module.exports.reviewCreate = function(req, res) {  
  var eventid = req.params.eventid;

  if (eventid) {  
    Review.create({  
      event_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(eventid),  
      someField: eventid  
      ...` This would just add the objectId to someField.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - yes I'm using expressjs. I'm following your edits and now understand the purpose of using save instead of create a bit more. The only part I trip up on is that for me EventReviewSchema is undefined since that is defined in the model not the controller.